# JQuery Hide/Show one, not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, mouseleave

I need help trying to figure out why this will only hide and show all of the elements for my hidden class. I've tried doing:

```
$("h2 > p").removeClass("hidden");
```

And it just won't work at all when I use that. I've also tried:

```
$(this).find('p').removeClass("hidden");
```

And that won't work at all either. As it's for an assignment, I can't edit the CSS or HTML directly and it's an introduction to JQuery, so the actual JavaScript and JQuery shouldn't be advanced at all. I just don't understand why it won't work with either of the two examples I've shown above. All I need is one of the answers to show, not every single one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h2").on('mouseover', function() {
        $("p").removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("h2").on('mouseout', function() {
        $("p").addClass("hidden");
    });
}); // end ready
```

This is the HTML portion including the classes that I'm trying to add and remove.

```
<body>
<section>
    <h1>jQuery FAQs</h1>
    <ul id="faq_rollovers">
        <li><h2>What is jQuery?</h2>
            <p class="hidden">jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions 
            that you're most likely to need as you develop web sites.</p>
        </li>
        <li><h2>Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</h2>
            <p class="hidden">Three reasons: It's free; It lets you get more done 
            in less time; All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</p>
        </li>
        <li><h2>Which is harder to learn: jQuery or JavaScript?</h2>
            <p class="hidden">For most functions, jQuery is significantly easier to learn 
            and use than JavaScript. But remember that jQuery is JavaScript.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>        
</section>
```

Note: Since the p element is hidden and you can't actually hover over it, I've elected to use the h2 element as the mouseover selector.

Comment: what styles does the class `hidden` add? have you tried `$("li p.hidden").show()`?

Comment: You can do this in jQuery with only one handler instead of two, or even without any JavaScript at all just by using CSS. Let me know if you want to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the p tag is not inside the h2 tag. You can either do:

```
$(this).siblings("p").removeClass("hidden");
```

Or:

```
$(this).parent().find("p").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always forget about siblings and parents (even in CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Try searching within the other h2 for the p tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h2").on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).siblings("p").removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("h2").on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).siblings("p").addClass("hidden");
    });
}); // end ready
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a bunch! I always forget about parents, siblings, and children!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "h2" ).hover( function() {
  $(this).next().removeClass("hidden");
}, function() {
  $(this).next().addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: and u can use .hover() function.